# Cypress test running locally but skipping tests on github actions

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, testcase

I am using github actions to run my test cases it is working fine for 2-3 months but now it is skipping test on github actions. Tried adding wait but still nothing change. Can anyone Guide?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fAD4.png)

I increase timeout but still skipping tests on github actions and giving this error

AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 10000ms: expected '/login' to match //dashboard$/

Comment: Are you able to get the specific logs for the tests? A random guess would be that something in your `before`/`beforeEach`/`after`/`afterEach` functions are failing, which would cause Cypress to skip all remaining tests in that spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `expected '/login' to match //dashboard$/` is a strong indication that the login failed.

This can mean

- the sever isn't running
- the server isn't accessible from Github
- the credentials have expired

All these fit with the chronology you describe, the tests ran for 3 months and suddenly stop.

I suggest you add a simple login-only test in a new repo and check the results for the above problems.

The other thing to check is `testIsolation`, see [Test Isolation as a Best Practice](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2023/03/08/test-isolation-as-a-best-practice/). This has been recently introduced, and the effect is to block credentials from carrying over from one test to another.

There are two steps you can take:

- temporarily turn off testIsolation in the config file

  ```js
  const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

  module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
      testIsolation: false,
    },
  })
  ```
- add a `cy.session()` command around your login to make the login credentials persist across multiple test

  ```js
  Cypress.Commands.add('loginWithUI', (username, password) => {
     cy.session(username, () => {
         cy.visit('/login')
         cy.get('#username-input').type(username)
         cy.get('#password-input').type(password)
         cy.get('#submit-button').click()
     })
  })
  ```